# Applying shaders to imported blender object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, import, shader-nodes

I'm importing the spinner from BR2049, so far I've been able to connect the normal, emission and base colour images to the respective places in the principled BSDF but the provided texture folder has some files with names I can't quite understand. I am new to blender so it's probably that I haven't worked with these shaders yet but they are ***ex_m*** and ***ex_r***. The ex part stands for external since the car has an exterior and interior. I'm confused by the letter after the ex.

Below is an image of the texture folder and my blender project view of the shader editor. Hopefully this gives enough material for someone to guide me.

[image: Folder highlighting files with strange names]
[image: blender project view]

Comment: Metallic and roughness ... ?

Comment: I suspect the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two different workflows for texture maps:

1. Albedo, Metalness, and Roughness - this looks like what you have:

_a = albedo
_m = metalness
_r = roughness

2. Diffuse, Specular, and Glossiness

1 is considered "Physically Based"(PBR) and 2 tends to be the "old school" way. In a lot of PBR texture sets, albedo, diffuse, and base color are the same thing. Technically albedo is an astronomy term and refers to the proportion of light reflected from a surface, so it's not really the same, but often you'll find the terms interchanged when it comes to texture maps.

If you do a web search for PBR textures you should be able to find a lot of information about the differences. If you see here there is a difference between even the base color maps in the two workflows:

[image]

This image is not mine; I got it from: https://substance3d.adobe.com/tutorials/courses/the-pbr-guide-part-2

Comment: Thanks Dale for this in-depth reply! Really cleared up my doubts, appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome @AgentiDiogenes! Can you please accept my answer then?